# HttpBin.org allows for any user to pass Digest authorization - only password is important

Tags: http, digest-authentication

I'm trying to check Digest authorization at https://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/test/pass. This is the end point to access a protected page under the user "test" and the password "pass".

The problem is that the site allows for successful authorization for any user. That is you navigate to the URL in your browser (or in your http-client under developement) and can enter anything for login (only correct password is important) and get 200 response and welcome json:

```
{
 "authenticated": true, 
 "user": "test"
}
```

This is the page I got after enter "bad":"pass" credentials in the browser popup dialog box.

Is it a known problem on the site or am I missing something?

The similar site httpbingo.org works as expected - it returns 401 if the user name is incorrect. But it's not so user-friendly as the first one.

The site of the author of httpbin.org (https://kennethreitz.org/) is down. Probably someone could shed some light?

NB. I found out that the [issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/httpbin/issues/463) is open for a while, but is not fixed still.

<sub>Probably the question could be closed.</sub>